# SwitchPreference Vibration

Tags: android

I have a SwitchPreference which is supposed to handle if the phone vibrates or not.

I currently have this:

```
 import android.os.Vibrator;
 ...

 public static final String PREF_CHANGE_THEME = "Changetheme";
 private SwitchPreference mSwitchPreference;
 private static SharedPreferences sPrefs;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mSwitchPreference = (SwitchPreference) findPreference(PREF_CHANGE_THEME);
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
sPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        mSwitchPreference = (SwitchPreference)

//If enabled execute the following:
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
     // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
     v.vibrate(500);
//Else: nothing
```

What is the correct syntax I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `preference` xml:

```
<SwitchPreference
    android:key="Changetheme"
    android:title="vibrate"
    android:defaultValue="false" />
```

And your java code should be something like:

```
public class SettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements onSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    public SwitchPreference mSwitchPreference;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.sample);

        mSwitchPreference = (SwitchPreference) findPreference(PREF_CHANGE_THEME); //Preference Key
       mSwitchPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals(PREF_CHANGE_THEME)) {
        boolean isEnable = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_CHANGE_THEME, false);
        //Do whatever you want here. This is an example.
        if (isEnable) {
            mSwitchPreference.setSummary("Enabled");
        } else {
            mSwitchPreference.setSummary("Disabled");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(TestPrefActivity.this);
        boolean isEnable = preferences.getBoolean(PREF_CHANGE_THEME, false);

        if (isEnable) {
            mSwitchPreference.setSummary("Enabled");
        } else {
            mSwitchPreference.setSummary("Disabled");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm having one little problem, i can't implement onSharedPreferenceChangeListener it says it can't resolve it.

Comment: @Nicolas your activity should implement onSharePreferenceChangeListener.

Comment: What i mean is that on Android Studio when copying the `public class SettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements onSharedPreferenceChangeListener {` The part that says onSharedPreferenceChangeListener turns red and says: 'Cannot resolve symbol'

Comment: @Nicolas updated my answer. add mSwitchPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this); to your activity.

Comment: I solved the problem! onSharedPreferenceChangeListener must start with capital O.
I added your new line of code and i'm getting an error on the (this) part. It says it can't apply it to this activity.
Everything else works fine, except that onSharedPreferenceChanged never gets called.

Comment: use inline click listener will fix your issue, mSwitchPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new onSharedPreferenceChangeListener {});